# A sum of three inradii

Tags: geometry

In rectangle $ABCD$, $AB=8$ and $BC=20$. Let $P$ be a point on $AD$ such that $\angle BPC=90^\circ$. If $R_1,R_2,R_3$ are the radii of the incircles of triangles $APB$, $BPC$ and $CPD$, what is the value
of $R_1+R_2+R_3$?

I spent hours and hours on this question.I tried to split the sides of the triangle in form of *a-r* ... However i didn't got the answer.This question is from Regional Mathematics Olympiad,India.

Comment: Where are the working/thoughts anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incircle radius $r$ of a right triangle with sides $a$, $b$ and $c$, where $c$ is the hypotenuse, can easily be shown to be

$$r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}.$$

[image]

Using this result, we get

$$R_1+R_2+R_3=\frac{AB+AP-BP}{2}+\frac{BP+CP-BC}{2}+\frac{CD+DP-CP}{2}$$

$$=\frac{AB+AP-BC+CD+DP}{2}=\frac{AB+AD+CD-BC}{2}$$

$$=\frac{AB+CD}{2}=\frac{2\cdot 8}{2}=8$$